# PHP increase packet size

Tags: php, networking, packet

Can I increase the packet size in php from php.ini file?

I need to send larger packets.

PHP is blocking me and giving an error:

> Warning: socket_write() [function.socket-write]: unable to write to socket [0]: A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself.

Any suggestions?

The code is:

$con=file_get_contents("image url");

$binary_data=base64_encode($con);

```
            $host = "123.456.78.9";
            $port = 1060;
            $message = $binary_data;
            // No Timeout 
            set_time_limit(0);


            $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP) or die("Could not create socket\n");

            socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");

            socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: You may have to manage the buffer yourself.  What OS?  Do you actually need larger packets themselves?  Can't you leave the fragmentation up to the lower layers?

Comment: I need to keep the packet as one whole packet because I am using UDP. If I segment the packet and send it I have to worry "if the packet is received on the server side?" and also worry "if segments are in the right order?".

Comment: Could it be done from the php.ini file? The max size I need to send is 1MB only

Comment: Its likely you will have to write each packet